# Table in c# windows form app

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a table for my Winform app and my question is what is the best control to use for it.
In my table i need to:

1. add columns once the user adds...
2. the values in the table cells oftenly updates and contain String types and double.

I serached the web for some kind of tamplates for tables or any other examples of designed controls with no luck, i know java and c++ have many of that kinds. If you  can recommand me of such sites...

Thanks.

Comment: Why is the build-in `DataGrid` control unsuitable for your purposes?

Comment: It could very well be, i am simply not familiar with all the controls, and dont want to get stuck with missing functionality later on. i will try it thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) should be enough. There's plenty of examples and tutorials, starting with [MSDN one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x64c23x.aspx) through [some tips](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33748/0/page/1) related to the control and finally more complex examples (not necessarily for DGV only) with [data binding](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/databinding_tutorial.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

DataGridView is best control to bind ur table below link reference this

link:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tips