# openFileDialoge in lexical analyzer c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, lexical-analysis

Asslamu Alikom ..

lexical analyzer in c# .
want to open file from computer to analyzing it when press "read file button",

[image]

this is the code :-

[image]

it showed to me the file ,, but I want it inside the form "white space in center" , not outside like this

[image]

---

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB199.png)

secondly,,
when I press symbol table " it organized line by line" ,,, how i can make it in table ?

" here the description "

[image]

thank guys ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For your first question, instead of using

   ```
   MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
   ```

   you would have to use :

   ```
   textBox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
   ```
2. For your second question, it really depends upon the framework that you are working with :

   If you are using WPF, I would recommend [WPF Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747133(v=vs.110).aspx).

   If you are using WinForms I would recommend DataGridView. See this StackOverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787617/table-in-c-sharp-windows-form-app).

Comment: thank u curvaman, it work now..,, but the second question, how i can do it by datagrid?? ,,, also I have question, the types of data in text file are" operator,integer,doublem literal" like this

   "(literal)",
                new Regex(@"\d+|\w+|\while|\;")));

do u know other types?
thank u!